# Coldfusion CFLock what type to use, application or session on an application obj

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

So my issue is as follows, are application does a number of query calls for every page call.  In order to remove these I decided to create an application obj or session obj.  I decided on an application obj, as I didn't want to add the obj to session scope.  Figured this could be bad with session scope to all the user's using up to much memory.  On the other hand if I use application obj, will I not slow down performance with additional locks all over the place.

Now the application obj is setting session variables do I need an application lock or a session lock.  From what I've been reading it seems that I don't even need a session lock. I don't see a race condition if this is a session obj, but a possible issue if it's an application obj.

```
**OnApplicationStart  
<cfset application.objSessionSecurity = createObject("component","common.cfc.SessionSecurity")>**


**later in the appliction.  
<cfset application.objSessionSecurity.setSessionSecurity(session.loginuser.persona_skey)>
<cfset application.objSessionSecurity.setSessionVaraibles()>**
```

Obj code.

```
<cffunction name="setSessionSecurity"  access="public" description="set session security privilages" >
    <cfargument name="personaSkey" required="true" type="numeric">        

    <cflock scope="session" timeout="30" type="EXCLUSIVE">
        <cfquery datasource="#request.dsn.otm#" name="allPrivs">
                SELECT pp.privilege_code
                FROM persona_privilege_vw pp
                WHERE pp.persona_skey = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#arguments.personaSkey#">
        </cfquery>

        <cfset session.PrivList = ValueArray(allPrivs.privilege_code)>        
    </cflock>
</cffunction>
```

So I guess this is two questions at the same time, should I use a sessionObj, or an application obj. ?

If an application Obj, do I still need the cflock around a session variable, and if so what type, application or session?

Thank you in advance.
David.

Comment: Maybe this will help, the `application` scope is for the entire application. ALL users share this scope.  The `session` scope if for a single user. Each user has their own session scope. So, yes, copying the exact same query to every user's session scope does not make a lot of sense and will use more memory than loading a single query in the application scope. Anything specific to a user goes in the session scope.

Comment: Also, don't put your lock around the query. That will force the lock to hold for as long as the query takes to execute and return.  Just put your lock tags around the code actually setting the session variable.

Comment: Tbh I'm not sure which scope (if either) should be used.  I noticed the query filters on `arguments,personaSkey`.  What's the source of that filter value and is it the same for ALL users? Could you elaborate a little more on how it's used?

Comment: @SOS, it is basically a user's primary key.  I need this in the session scope as the objective is to hold onto a person's rights to the application.

Comment: (Update) Then the query data is user/session specific, so you would *not* want to use the application scope. Doing that would result in returning the same permissions to all users.  If it is okay for the application to check permissions once per session, then just run the query once inside onSessionStart of your application.cfc and set the appropriate session variables.  No need to store the query in the session scope, or use locking. CF automatically locks the session scope inside onSessionStart, Locking is only necessary when that method is called manually, which you wouldn't do here.